# How to SUM in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I select, the sum of the **first non-zero** value from a list of columns- without including the column in the group by. This is the query that I wrote, but I have to include all these columns in the group by (which I dont want to do)

```
Select CpnyID,H.Acct,A.Descr, 
case when H.YtdBal12 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal12)
     when H.YtdBal11 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal06)
     when H.YtdBal10 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal10)
     when H.YtdBal09 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal09)
     when H.YtdBal08 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal08)
     when H.YtdBal07 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal07)
     when H.YtdBal06 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal06)
     when H.YtdBal05 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal05)
     when H.YtdBal04> 0 then sum(H.YtdBal04)
     when H.YtdBal03 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal03)
     when H.YtdBal02  > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal02)
     when H.YtdBal01 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal01)
     when H.YtdBal00 > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal00)
END
from AcctHist H,Account A,PSSFAAssetClass C
where A.Acct = H.Acct
and (H.Acct = C.Acct or H.Acct  = C.AccDeprAcct) 
and FiscYr = 2013
group by CpnyID,H.Acct,A.Descr
order by CpnyID,H.Acct
```

Comment: What if `H.YtdBal12 > 0 AND H.YtdBal11 > 0` for instance ? Do you want to sum both values too ? It would be clearer with sample data and expected output.

Comment: I only want to sum the first, non-zeo value. So if ytdbal12 > 0, then it should return the sum(ytdbal12) and should not check any further.

Comment: Depending on the values and the wished result something like
`case when SUM(H.YtdBal12) > 0 then sum(H.YtdBal12) ......`

Comment: That doesn't make things any clearer. Say you have two rows : 1: YtdBal12 = 1 and YtdBal06=0. Second the other way around. What should the query take into account ? SUM(YtdBal12) ? SUM(YtdBal06) ? SUM(YtdBal12 on the first row + YtdBal06 on the second row) ?

Comment: I agree with X L Ant.  More would be helpful.  If the query above is returning what you want but just has too many columns (3?), make it a subquery and select what you want from it.

Comment: It is a very poor prgramming practice to use implict joins. Don;t do that anymore. They are far more subject to getting the wrong data and are harder to mainatin. They were replaced over 20 years ago, who you use application code that had been replaced that many years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SUM(COALESCE(H.YtdBal12, H.YtdBal11, H.YtdBal10...)
```

You may need a NULLIF() on each column if the values are actually 0 and not just null.
Like:

```
SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(H.YtdBal12,0),NULLIF(H.YtdBal11,0), etc...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to move the `sum()` outside the case:

```
Select CpnyID, H.Acct, A.Descr, 
Sum(case when H.YtdBal12 > 0 then H.YtdBal12
     when H.YtdBal11 > 0 then H.YtdBal06
     when H.YtdBal10 > 0 then H.YtdBal10
     when H.YtdBal09 > 0 then H.YtdBal09
     when H.YtdBal08 > 0 then H.YtdBal08
     when H.YtdBal07 > 0 then H.YtdBal07
     when H.YtdBal06 > 0 then H.YtdBal06
     when H.YtdBal05 > 0 then H.YtdBal05
     when H.YtdBal04> 0 then H.YtdBal04
     when H.YtdBal03 > 0 then H.YtdBal03
     when H.YtdBal02  > 0 then H.YtdBal02
     when H.YtdBal01 > 0 then H.YtdBal01
     when H.YtdBal00 > 0 then H.YtdBal00
END)
from AcctHist H 
join Account A
    On A.Acct = H.Acct
JOIN PSSFAAssetClass C
    on (H.Acct = C.Acct or H.Acct  = C.AccDeprAcct) 
where FiscYr = 2013
group by CpnyID, H.Acct, A.Descr
order by CpnyID, H.Acct;
```

I also fixed the `join` syntax.